# How can I externalise my selenium setup in order to make my selenium tests configurable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, automated-tests

I would like to externalise my selenium tests setting in order to make them more configurable.
I would like to externalise my testURL and my node URLS.

Here is my code :

```
public void setup () throws MalformedURLException  

{       //the URL of the application to be tested  
    TestURL = "http://frstmwarwebsrv2.orsyptst.com:9000";
            //Hub URL
    BaseURL = "http://10.2.128.126";
            //Node1 URL
    winURL = "http://10.2.128.120:5556/wd/hub";
            //Node2 URL
    androidURL ="http://10.2.128.120:5555/wd/hub";
```

At the moment I have added this setup function in every test I would like to have it in an XML file for an example in order to make it configurable, any suggestions?

Thanks

Thanks for your help

Update :

Here is what i did so far :

Added a config.properties file with this content :

```
# This is my test.properties file
AppURL = http://************
HubURL= http://*****************
WinURL= http://*********/wd/hub
AndroidURL =
iOSURL
```

And created a classe to read properties :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadPropertiesFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("config.properties");
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();

            Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
            while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

when running this i get this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (The system cannot find the file  specified)    
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ReadPropertiesFile.main(ReadPropertiesFile.java:15)
```

my properties file is under src folder

Comment: Well copied the file under the project source and it worked thanks Niall :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two basic ways you could do this are:

1. Pass in JVM argument and access it using `System.getProperty(...)`
2. Externalize your configuration in to properties files, like [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file.html)

I recently implemented the second one in my Selenium tests and can expand this answer to give more details if you need them.

Comment: Hi Niall, yes I would appreciate if you can expand your second solution. In my case the config keys I need are the tested application URL, hub URL and node URL. I have visted the link you send and I did get how to create the properties file and read it. my question is how I add thess properties in my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ziwdigforbugs Do you still need this or have you resolved it based on your comment on the original question?

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, I resolved it that I created Java class called `Environment` to store information about given Environment:

Few snippets of code:

```
 public enum NameOfEnvironment {
    SYSTEMTEST, ACCEPTANCE
}
```

stores the Name of given Environment :)

```
public String getBaseUrl() {
    switch (actualEnvironment) {
        case SYSTEMTEST: {
            baseUrl = getPrefix() + "172.23.32.251:9092/pages/index.html";
            break;
        }
```

will return me the URL to the environment. And on beginning of the test I have something like this:

```
 public static final Environment USED_ENVIRONMENT = new Environment(Environment.NameOfEnvironment.SYSTEMTEST);
```

And later on I just call `USED_ENVIRONMENT.getBaseUrl()` which will return me the link which is being actual for current run

Btw, to fill in the blanks, here is the constructor f the class

```
 public Environment(NameOfEnvironment env) {
    this.actualEnvironment = env;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, but what i want to do if possible is to externalise completely the set-up from the code and move it to an external file so that the person who is executing the code won't have to get in to the code to change config.

Comment: Ok. I know it can be done, but my programmer experience is really low. But you could do it. Try searching on "how to read a file" and such...